# How to compare two lists according to a specific requirement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a reference list `my_ref = [1,2,3]`. I am trying to create a function `foo` that takes a list of length 3 (let's call it `list_n`). `foo` will check if adding just value 1 to only one arbitrary element of `list_n`, makes each element of `list_n` be greater than each element of `my_ref` pairwise. Since this explanation may be confusing, I present several examples as follows:

Example 1:

```
my_ref = [1,2,3]

 list1 = [0,2,4]
```

If number 1 is added to one of the zeroes, then we have [0,2,4], so now all elements of list1 are greater than equal to all greatest elements of my_list, i.e. 1 = 1, 2=2 and 4 > 3. So the function should return `True` with that element to be added by 1, which was 0 in this example.

Example 2:

```
my_ref = [1,2,3]
list_2 = [2,2,1]
```

If number 1 is added to one of the two's, then we have [3,2,1], so all elements of list1 are greater than equal to all elements of my_list, i.e. 3 = 3, 2=2 and 1 = 1. Therefore, the function should return `True` with that element to be added by 1, which was 2 in this example.

Example 3:

```
my_ref = [1,2,3]
list_3 = [5,3,1]
```

By adding number 1 to any one's of `list_3`, we will have: 5>3, 3>2, 2>1. Hence, the function returns `True` with the number 1.

BUT

Example 4:

```
my_ref = [1,2,3]
list_3 = [0,2,1]
```

There is no way to add number 1 to any elements of `list_3` so that the explained requirement is met. Thus, the function should return `False` with None.

I have coded as follows:

```
def fun(l):
    my_ref = [1, 2, 3] 
    
    l.sort()
    for i in range(2, 0, -1):
        if l[i] < ref[i] and sum(l) >= 5:
            return True, l[i]

    return False, None
```

It works fine with most examples but not all. For instance, `print(fun([4, 1, 0]))` returns `(True, 1)` which is wrong, instead it should return `(False, None)`. I have tried a lot. Each time, the function with some examples work fine but with some examples doesn't. I hope my the problem is now clear.

How do I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: [4, 1, 0, 0] sums to 5, and when you sort it the 1 lines up with 2 in your ref list. So 1 is less than 2 and the sum meets your criteria so returning (True, 1) is correct.

Comment: @acrobat Thank you for your comment. The size of each list should be 3. I have updated the question.

Comment: the 1 and the 2 still line up, and the sum is still 5 so it still meets your 'True' criteria. In your loop before the 'if' comparison line add a `print(l[i], ref[i])` line so you can see what's being paired up and compared.

Comment: Shouldn't  the line ```if l[i] < ref[i] and sum(l) >= 5:``` be replaced with ```if l[i] < ref[i] and sum(l) >= sum(my_ref)```:

Comment: @acrobat Please note the criteria is not sum = 5 but the explanation in the question. If we add 1 to any of `[4,1,0]` always one element is less than an element in the `my_ref` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func(l):
    superior = 0
    ref = [0, 1, 2, 3]

    l1 = l[:]
    l2 = l[:]
    l3 = l[:]
    l4 = l[:]

   l1[0]+=1
   l2[1]+=1
   l3[2]+=1
   l4[3]+=1

   targets = [l1, l2, l3, l4]

   for i in range(len(targets)):
        if get_superior_count(targets[i]) >= 3:
            return True, i
   return False, None

def get_superior_count(l):
    ref = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    target = l[:]
    count = 0
    l.sort()
    m = 3
    n = 3

    while m > 0 and n > 0:
        if target[m] >= ref[n]:
            count+=1
            target.pop(m)
            ref.pop(n)
            m-=1
        n-=1
    return count
```

Not sure it is what you want (and it's a bit ugly) but seems working with your examples.

Comment: Thank you. I think if in `func` you change `return True, i` to `return True, get_superior_count(l)` then it works fine. To figure out what I mean please check `[2,2,0,1]` as the input of `func`.

Comment: But with `func([3, 1, 1, 1])` what you have coded i.e `return True, i` works not what I mentioned. So the function still needs modification.

Comment: func([2,2,0,1]) returns (True, 0) cause [3,2,0,1] is ok no ?
3>=3, 2>=2 and 1>=1 

And func([3,1,1,1]) returns (True, 1) cause [3, 2, 1, 1] is ok too : 3>=3, 2>=2 and 1>=1 ?

For me it seems ok or I misunderstood something ?

It should return True when at least 3 members of the list are individually > than the ref list
And the index is the one that is incremented ?

Answer (score 1):

```
def checker(my_ref, l):
    if sum(l) +1 < sum(my_ref):
        return False
    return True

def align_lists(my_ref, l):
    return list(zip(sorted(my_ref), sorted(l)))

def compare_paired_elements(l, my_ref):
    requires_bump = 0

    if not checker(my_ref, l):
       return False
    
    for pair in align_lists(my_ref, l):
        ref_num = pair[0]
        num = pair[1]

        if num < ref_num:
            if num + 1 < ref_num:
                continue
            if num + 1 == ref_num:
                requires_bump += 1
                print(num, "needs a bump to match", ref_num)
    
    if requires_bump > 1:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Examples:

```
> my_ref = [1,2,3]
> l = [0,2,4]
> compare_paired_elements(l, my_ref)
0 needs a bump to match 1
True
> l = [4,1,0]
> compare_paired_elements(l, my_ref)
0 needs a bump to match 1
1 needs a bump to match 2
False
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to apply this to lists of size 4 where `my_ref = [0,1,2,3]`?

Comment: @MLL Yes, that's the idea behind my_ref being an argument -- its generic. Try it out.  Likewise, you can easily adjust requires_bump so you can adjust the comparison  beyond just +1.